# How to get the sum and the names of all the users from all voice channels Disocrd?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I use :

```
import discord
```

I need to get from each voice channel amount all users and then get their names (usernames). How to do it?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: @Wright i have find this http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#channel and idk how to get  voice_members

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the voice channel object. I recommend you use the voice channel's id. The command could look as follows:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def vcmembers(ctx, voice_channel_id):
    #First getting the voice channel object
    voice_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.channels, id = voice_channel_id)
    if not voice_channel:
        return await client.say("That is not a valid voice channel.")

    members = voice_channel.voice_members
    member_names = '\n'.join([x.name for x in members])

    embed = discord.Embed(title = "{} member(s) in {}".format(len(members), voice_channel.name),
                          description = member_names,
                          color=discord.Color.blue())

    return await client.say(embed = embed)
```

And would work like this:

[image]

Where the number at the end is the channel id. If you don't know how to get the channel id, right click the channel and click Copy ID.

[image]

If you can't see the Copy ID, turn on Developer Mode in your `Settings > Appearance > Developer Mode`

Comment: `ctx.message.server.channels` didn't work for me (No such field 'server' in 'message)

Answer (score 2):

You can also get all the members of a voice channel like this (updated for discord.py versions 1.0.0+):

```
@client.command(brief="returns a list of the people in the voice channels in the server",)
async def vcmembers(ctx):
    #First getting the voice channels
    voice_channel_list = ctx.guild.voice_channels

    #getting the members in the voice channel
    for voice_channels in voice_channel_list:
        #list the members if there are any in the voice channel
        if len(voice_channels.members) != 0:
            if len(voice_channels.members) == 1:
                await ctx.send("{} member in {}".format(len(voice_channels.members), voice_channels.name))
            else:
                await ctx.send("{} members in {}".format(len(voice_channels.members), voice_channels.name))
            for members in voice_channels.members:
                #if user does not have a nickname in the guild, send thier discord name. Otherwise, send thier guild nickname
                if members.nick == None:
                    await ctx.send(members.name)
                else:
                    await ctx.send(members.nick)
```